# C# WPF. ListView переопределить событие множественного выделения.

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте, возникла задача делать выделение нескольких строк в ListView контроле. Выделение нескольких строк работает при зажатом Ctrl. И при отжатом Ctrl сбрасывается предыдущее выделение многих строк и выделяется 1 строка. Мне нужно чтобы мультивыделение работало сразу (без Ctrl). Т.е нажали на строку левой кнопкой мыши она выделилась нажали на след, она тоже выделилась, нажали на выделенную строку - снялось выделение.

Возможно есть другие контроллы для такого поведения?

Answer (score 1):

Нет, контролов нет, потому что такое поведение контролов (множественное выделение лишь при нажатом <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) прописано в Vista+ UI Guidelines.

Но вы можете сделать нестандартное поведение самостоятельно, обрабатывая `PreviewMouseDown` и самостоятельно устанавливая/снимая выделение с элементов.

---

Вот код:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionMode="Multiple" PreviewMouseDown="OnMouseDown"/>
```

```
void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox lb = (ListBox)sender;
    var point = e.GetPosition(lb);
    var o = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(lb, point).VisualHit;
    ListBoxItem clickedContainer = null;
    while (o != lb)
    {
        clickedContainer = o as ListBoxItem;
        if (clickedContainer != null)
            break;
        o = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(o);
    }
    if (clickedContainer == null)
        return;
    var clickedItem = lb.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(clickedContainer);
    if (lb.SelectedItems.Contains(clickedItem))
        lb.SelectedItems.Remove(clickedItem);
    else
        lb.SelectedItems.Add(clickedItem);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, интересно. в конце кода   e.Handled = true;, чтобы не слать событие дальше?

Comment: @Aldmi: Ага, чтобы подавить «нормальную» реакцию на клик.

Answer (score 1):

Походу совсем заработался. Нужно выставить SelectionMode="Multiple"

ну и чтобы прибайндиться к списку выделенных элементов нужно переопределить поведение.

```
     <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
     <wpfExtensions:MultiSelectionBehavior SelectedItems="{Binding Path=ListWithoutStops, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
      </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Если кому- то интересно могу привести код MultiSelectionBehavior.

MultiSelectionBehavior:

```
    public class MultiSelectionBehavior : Behavior<ListBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        if (SelectedItems != null)
        {
            AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Clear();
            foreach (var item in SelectedItems)
            {
                AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }

    public IList SelectedItems
    {
        get { return (IList)GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItems", typeof(IList), typeof(MultiSelectionBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, SelectedItemsChanged));

    private static void SelectedItemsChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var behavior = o as MultiSelectionBehavior;
        if (behavior == null)
            return;

        var oldValue = e.OldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        var newValue = e.NewValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;

        if (oldValue != null)
        {
            oldValue.CollectionChanged -= behavior.SourceCollectionChanged;
            behavior.AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= behavior.ListBoxSelectionChanged;
        }
        if (newValue != null)
        {
            behavior.AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Clear();
            foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)newValue)
            {
                behavior.AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Add(item);
            }

            behavior.AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += behavior.ListBoxSelectionChanged;
            newValue.CollectionChanged += behavior.SourceCollectionChanged;
        }
    }

    private bool _isUpdatingTarget;
    private bool _isUpdatingSource;

    void SourceCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isUpdatingSource)
            return;

        try
        {
            _isUpdatingTarget = true;

            if (e.OldItems != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in e.OldItems)
                {
                    AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Remove(item);
                }
            }

            if (e.NewItems != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
                {
                    AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _isUpdatingTarget = false;
        }
    }

    private void ListBoxSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isUpdatingTarget)
            return;

        var selectedItems = this.SelectedItems;
        if (selectedItems == null)
            return;

        try
        {
            _isUpdatingSource = true;

            foreach (var item in e.RemovedItems)
            {
                selectedItems.Remove(item);
            }

            foreach (var item in e.AddedItems)
            {
                selectedItems.Add(item);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _isUpdatingSource = false;
        }
    }

}
```

После переопределения поведения работает TwoWay Binding на коллекцию выделенных элементов.

Comment: Приведите, конечно! Наверняка пригодится.